# How to handle exceptions in async methods that return Task<Something>

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I am taksed to introduce exception logging in a layer of middleware. From top to bottom of this middleware the calls are as follows:

```
//In layer C
public async Task<List<Foo>> GetFoo(GetFooRequest request)
{
    return await _repository.GetFooAsync(request);
} 

//In layer D
public async Task<List<Foo>> GetFooAsync(GetFooRequest request)
{
    return await _context.Foo.Where(x=> x.FooId=request.FooID).ToListAsync();
}
```

I would like to log in Layer C, however, Task returns a System.Void, as such the compiler complains about the code below. I understand why the code below fails but I am having problems finding a solution pattern or practice of logging in layer C.

```
 //In layer C
public async Task<List<Foo>> GetFoo(GetFooRequest request)
{
    try
    {
        return await _repository.GetFooAsync(request);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        base.LogException(e)      //<- Not all code paths return a value
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can create a class that Invokes methods and do logging there, such as return await `LogInvoker.Invoke(_repository.GetFooAsync...)`? Or does this require refactoring the current flow between the layers?

Comment: Since you're catching the exception what value do you want to return after you've called "LogException` ? It's either got to be some sort of `List<>` or you re-throw the exception.

Comment: Perhaps an empty list. That  seems better than throwing the exception again.

Comment: How is that better? Now the calling method has no idea that something went wrong so it will happily continue. Maybe it will work, maybe it won't; maybe it will return an expected result, maybe it won't.

Comment: General pattern is if you ask for something that should be there and it comes back not there, empty or null, then it means there was a problem getting it and the error has already logged. The top layers are lightweight and have no logging and if they need to they can return whatever back out to the client 403 or whatever. Although some situations such as search functionality would probably just return "not found". But at least the error would be known internally.

Comment: I see this was an entirely boneheaded question now that I am out of the weeds and look back at it. I was dealing with 100 things related to DI and threading at once and thought the red squiggly was an compiler error related to my pattern. I neglected to realize the simplest issue that I was not returning a result. I thought the async pattern was cauing an issue. I would delete this post but would not want to penalize the individual who answered. Who knows someone may find use out of it, if not to laugh at my temporary loss of all things sensible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got to do something at the end of the `catch` block. You mention in the question comments that you'd be prepared to return an empty list if something goes wrong:

```
public async Task<List<Foo>> GetFoo(GetFooRequest request)
{
    try
    {
        return await _repository.GetFooAsync(request);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        base.LogException(e);
        return new List<Foo>();
    }
}
```

or rethrow the exception, if that makes sense to your application:

```
public async Task<List<Foo>> GetFoo(GetFooRequest request)
{
    try
    {
        return await _repository.GetFooAsync(request);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        base.LogException(e);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think log and return null will work. For me null means something went wrong.